# Need to restore applications folder from an old time machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, migration-assistant

I have a macbook air running OSX 10.7.5. I have had a problem with the App Store not connecting. Apple could not resolve it, so I have done a clean install. Now I wish to restore various folders from Time Machine, but not the most recent Applications Folder, as the App Store program is not working.

So, how do I restore an older Applications folder to my clean SSD and import all the necessary support files that are not stored in the Applications folder?

Also, where do I find, and how can I import all my user defined files (my Application preferences) that will allow the programs to have the settings I had stored for them before I had to wipe and reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Run Migration Assistant and tell it to move Applications and settings from the Time Machine backup of choice.

If your SSD is clean or only has a junk account, you should be able to move back your real user account and settings as well as all applications in one clean migration.

It will check for problems like you already having a user account and let you know if you will have collisions and how it will handle them.